# Adding array that has text with spaces into TextArea using JQuery and append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append to my page an array inside a TextArea and I break it every time I have a space between characters in array.
Let's say I have ingredients in array: "rice", "oil", "soy milk", "apple" I am using the following JQuery syntax:

```
$("#container").append("<input type = 'text' id = 'ingredients' value = " + ingArrayTest+ ">");
```

My final result will have only: "rice, oil, soy" because space will break the rest of the array in the display. Is there a way to wrap the array so it doesn't happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the intent to not how milk or apple?  Or to show them?

Comment: There's a lot of array functions in JS. You can join your array for example. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: Do you want each array element on a new line?

Comment: Irfornal --> I want to show them all in the same line (textarea in this case)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple array join, assuming I am reading this correctly.  Try

```
ingArrayTest.join("\n")
```

... in place of ingArrayTest above.  Spaces could be used in place of the '\n' ...

**BASED ON DISCUSSION**, try:

```
var ingArrayTest = ["Milk", "Soy Milk", "Apple"];
var ingString = ingArrayTest.join(" ");
$("#container").append("<input type='text' id='ingredients' value='" + ingString  + "'>");
```

...note the single quotes near value. Watch single quotes versus double; very important.

Comment: try ... `.join(" ")` ... assuming ingArrayTest is the array.

Comment: The previous will make one string with SPACES as the separator.

Comment: Still doesn't look good. This is the HTML that is generated: <input type="text" id="ingredients" dir="rtl" size="70" value="rice" "oil"="" "soy="" milk"="">

Comment: <input type="text" id="ingredients" dir="rtl" size="70" value="rice" "oil" "soy milk">

Comment: With my edit, you should be able to examine the string after generation to see what might be causing the issue.  Use console.log ...

Comment: rfornal --> The console.log shows:  "rice", "oil", "soy milk"